# Method for expectation on discrete random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

Say I have a discrete random variable $X$ and $X = -2$ has probability 0.4 and $X = 5$ has probability 0.6.

When I calculate $E[X]$ I get $E[X] = (-2 * 0.4) + (5 * 0.6) = 2.2$

My understanding was that the generalization looked something like:
$E[h(X)] = \sum_{x}h(x)f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the probability mass function.

So then I was getting lost when trying to calculate
$E[2 + 1/X]$ for the same discrete random variable.

I assumed it was:
$E[2 + 1/X] = \left(2 + \dfrac{1}{-2}\right)\times0.4 + \left(2 + \dfrac{1}{5}\right)\times0.6 $

Am I on the right track here? Or did I miss something?

Comment: That's exactly the law of the unconscious statistician.

Comment: That's what I thought. But is there something I'm not accounting for when there's a reciprocal term in there? Because the answer I'm getting doesn't match the solution

Comment: Did you have a calculation error somewhere?  (...and what is the solution you were given?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I assumed it was: $E[2+1/X] = (2 + 1/(-2))\cdot 0.4 + (2 + 1/5)\cdot 0.6$

You assumed correctly.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf E[2+1/X] &= (2 + 1/(-2))\cdot 0.4 + (2 + 1/5)\cdot 0.6\\&= 2~+~\dfrac{-1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{2}{5}+\dfrac{1}{5}\cdot\dfrac{3}{5}\\&=\dfrac{48}{25}&&=1+\dfrac{23}{25}\\&=1.96\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. In this case, using your notation, $h(x)=2+1/x$, and $E(h(X))=h(-2) 0.4+h(5) 0.6$.